# What do you call the first letter of a syllable?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Random Example:

> **Superman**

The word Superman has 3 syllables. ***S***, ***P*** and ***M*** are the first letter of each syllable. Is there a term for ***S***, ***P*** and ***M***?

If I were to describe I form an acronym ***S.P.M*** from the word *Superman*, the sentence below is the best I can manage.

> S.P.M is formed by the first letter of each syllable of the word Superman?

I don't feel it sounds right. How could I better describe it?

Comment: Syllables have sounds, not letters.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist! Is there a way/term to describe it?

Comment: Maybe ‘*initial consonants*’ ...

Comment: @tchrist, every dictionary I've ever used has shown how to break up each word into syllables, indicating which letters belong to each syllable. Are there any examples of English words where this isn't possible?

Comment: @ThePhoton would you suggest, as the OP did, that SPM are the first three letters that make up the syllables of *superman*? Who does? I normally split syllables using a dot , e.g.  su•per•man

Comment: The first letter of a syllable is simply called "the first letter" it is not the *onset* that refers to the *sounds*.

Comment: @Jim: the first letter of a syllable doesn't have to be a consonant: deescalate, cooperate, egg,...

Comment: ‘@TonyK - I know.  I immediately thought of ’aorta’.   But in OP’s case, SPM, it worked.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  am confused now. The *sounds*... isn't the *sounds* made up by the *letters*?

Comment: In your system ACD would indicate where the syllables break in "accident"  but would a learner understand a•cci•dent or ac•ci•dent? Another example, “execution“ would it be  e•c•t or e•x•c•t? A learner might think that *tion* is pronounced with a hard "t", if you look in the dictionary,  execution has four syllables – [ **ek-si-kyoo-shuh n** ] Syllables are sounds, not letters. In English letters and different combination of letters attempt to represent these sounds.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks. I see what you mean now. The example is just to illustrate what I am referring to, it doesn't mean I am putting it in application.

Comment: @ThePhoton I would say that strictly speaking, in a dictionary, what you are referring to as "how to break up each word into syllables" is *actually* "where it is possible to hyphenate" as those markings are in the spelling. The syllable boundaries are denoted in the pronunciations. You can see e.g. in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apostasy that there are only two possible hyphenation points, dividing the word into 3 segments, but it's 4 syllables long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is called the **onset**:

> The *nucleus* is usually the vowel in the middle of a syllable. The ***onset*** is the sound or sounds occurring before the nucleus, and the *coda* (literally 'tail') is the sound or sounds that follow the nucleus.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Typical_model)

Comment: I believe it is. Thanks @Laurel

Comment: A syllable's *onset* is all of its sounds before its nucleus, not just the first one. This relates to sounds, but the OP asks about letters. As tchrist said, syllables have sounds, not letters. How do you map a word's sounds to its letters? Which syllables do you put silent letters into? If (going by the maximum onset principle) you say that the second syllables of "calming" and "bombing" begin with /m/, do you say they both begin with "m" (which would put the L into the first but the silent B into the second) -- or what?

Comment: @RosieF And how to deal with clusters? For example, the word "street" has only 1 syllable, onset of which is /str/ (and "str"). But the OP probably want to abbreviate "street" as "S".

Comment: @trolley813 Yup. If *Street* is the example, the letter I am referring to is *S*.

Comment: @trolley813 Clusters, good point. Toe-strap and toast-rack. (The point of that pair of words is to show that it could be argued that dividing a compound word into its elements overrides the maximum onset principle.)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the comments here are totally correct, but perhaps may not be fully explaining the answer to the asker, which is asking for help because they are not native in English.  Jalene, I am quite certain there is no term for this.  It is just "the first letter of the syllable, as Leo indicates.  "onset" is the closest thing ,but that really is a description of the sound, not the letter itself.  As you know, one letter may have different sounds, and some sounds are made by combinations of letters.

While Tchrist is correct that a syllable has a sound, it doesn't really address the question, and syllables of course "have" letters, which are used to represent those sounds when written.

There is probably no word for this, because there is generally no need.  An acronym uses the first letter of each word, generally https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acronym no syllables.  This is not a common think to do, to initialize syllables, and I struggle to think of a good usage for it.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to think of how to best explain what I am referring to. It was just a random example. :p